# Cannot launch Worklight Server Configuration Tool - missing configuration-tool.sh and ppc64 binaries for tool

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I've installed Worklight v6.1.0 and the Application Center on a Power System ppc64 RHEL 6.5 Linux partition.  I'm at the point where I try to launch the configuration tool from the application menu and run into the "missing" configuration-tool.sh.

I've reviewed the installation and am curious why the post install scripts do not build this tool based on my environment?  Of course I'm assuming that is what would finish building the script from the template found in the /opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/install/shortcuts directory.  I've followed IBM's posted download and installation instructions to the t.  I do notice in my /opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/ConfigurationTool directory I do not have any sub-directory for the ppc64.

I've searched through developerWorks, Google, and this site without finding a hit.  This make me think I don't have the right install images for this platform.  Bottomline, is I need the binaries for the ppc64 configuration tool that should be found under the /opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/ConfigurationTool.  How or where can I get them?

Thanks,
Randy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Server Configuration Tool is available only on Windows and Linux (x86) and Mac OS in Worklight 6.1 (see the Worklight 6.1 doc for details -> http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_using_server_config_tool.html )

If you can't use the Server Configuration Tool on your platform, the easiest way to get started with deploying a Project WAR file and its console is to use on of the ant file examples documented at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/c_ant_tasks_sample_config_files.html.

Actually, the Server Configuration Tool acts mostly as a graphic front end to create and run those ant files.

Comment: I forgot to add that you will find, for WL 6.1, a 'ant' launcher in <WorklightInstallDir>/shortcuts/ant

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I thought I combed the document thoroughly to determine whether the tools was supported on ppc64.  I would like to suggest to IBM they make that one little line in that link a little more obvious  In the meantime, I've already been pursuing the deployment via ANT.  Again, thanks for finding the fine print.